# Insert WooCommerce product id dynamically in shortcode [add_to_cart]

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'd like to create an add to cart button for the default variation.

Is there a way to do it using shortcode [add_to_cart] and dynamically get the ID and variation set by default ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [See WC docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-19) You can define the ID of the product. I think in this case you can also specify the ID of the variation.
Did you try to set the default variation for that product, and then I think by adding the product to cart, it will add the default variation.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking to dynamically get those values so I can use the same template for all my pages. Any idea how to proceed ? Thank you.